# error message : file does not exist at path 'file://localhost/volumes/tablecellview.xib'

Tags: iphone

I've made the transfer of my application from one mac to another, and when I tried to build it, the following error message appears : file does not exist at path 'file://localhost/volumes/tablecellview.xib' 
So I don't know how  how to deal with that !

Answer (score 1):

right-click on the file in your project view and check to what path it points. If necessary you can adjust it there